# Existence of an irreducible $L$-submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose $L$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra. Let $V$ be an $L$-module (i.e. $V$ is a vector space which $L$ acts upon). We are assuming that $V$ has a finite dimension. My question is the following:

> Does $V$ necessarily contain an irreducible $L$-submodule?

For reference, irreducible $L$-module is one which has only two $L$-submodules, namely $0$ and itself. By the way, $0$ subspace does *not* count as an irreducible submodule (following the convention in Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*).

I suspect that the answer is 'yes', but perhaps a clever counterexample exist?

Comment: If you assume $V$ is finite dimensional you can prove the result by induction on dimension.  If $V$ is not irreducible it contains a proper submodule $W\subset V$ which by induction contains an irreducible.  For general algebras it is not always true that infinite dimensional modules contain irreducible submodules, I suspect the same is true for lie algebras.

Comment: @mikevaiana: Dear Mike, I just edited the post to add the assumption that $V$ has finite dimension (infinite-dimensional modules are too hard for me :)). Consider posting your comment as an answer. It looks great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, every finite dimensional $L$-module, $V,$ contains an irreducible submodule.  The proof is by induction on the dimension of $V.$

The base case is clear since any $1$ dimensional module is automatically irreducible.  For the induction step assume $\dim V > 1.$ If $V$ is irreducible we are done so suppose it is not.  Then by definition of irreducible $V$ contains a proper submodule $W\subset V.$  By the induction assumption $W$ contains an irreducible submodule hence so does $V.$

Comment: (Technically, one needs to exclude the possibility of $V$ being $0$-dimensional).